# Painting over QGraphicsItem without scaling

Tags: qt5, qgraphicsitem

I have a custom class derived from the **QGraphicsRectItem**. All I need is to draw a frame over this item and some block on the bottom right. The width of the frame and size of the block are fixed, but the item can be scaled using **QGraphicsItem::setTransform** function. The problem is that when I try to map the bounding rect of the item to the view, I get an inaccurate output rect and this rect gets out of the bounds of the item. Please, look at the code below:

```cpp
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include "ui_Test.h"

#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class MyItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    explicit MyItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = Q_NULLPTR) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    void drawVolumeIndicator(QPainter *painter);
};

class Test : public QMainWindow, private Ui::TestClass
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Test(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

```cpp
#include "Test.h"

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

MyItem::MyItem(QGraphicsItem *parent)
    : QGraphicsRectItem(parent)
{}

void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QGraphicsRectItem::paint(painter, option, widget);

    drawVolumeIndicator(painter);
}

void MyItem::drawVolumeIndicator(QPainter *painter)
{
    static const auto blockColor = QColor(QStringLiteral("#0097a7"));
    static const auto frameColor = QColor(QStringLiteral("#660097a7"));

    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto blockSize = QSize(12, 40);
    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto blockMargin = 2;
    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto frameWidth = 4;

    const auto outputRect = painter->transform().mapRect(boundingRect());

    painter->save();
    painter->resetTransform();

    // draw block
    const auto x = outputRect.right() - frameWidth - blockMargin - blockSize.width();
    const auto y = outputRect.bottom() - frameWidth - blockMargin - blockSize.height();
    painter->fillRect(QRect(QPoint(x, y), blockSize), blockColor);

    // draw frame
    painter->setBrush(Qt::transparent);
    painter->setPen(QPen(frameColor, frameWidth, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin));
    painter->drawRect(outputRect);

    painter->restore();
}

Test::Test(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    resize(200, 400);

    auto item = new MyItem;
    item->setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
    item->setPen(QPen(Qt::transparent));
    item->setRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    // set scale for the item
    QTransform transform;
    transform.scale(1, 3);
    item->setTransform(transform);

    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(item);

    auto view = new QGraphicsView;
    view->setScene(scene);

    QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

Here's how it looks without scaling:
[image: without scaling]

And here's how it looks with scaling:
[image: with scaling]

Comment: Do you want the block to scale in the same way as the rectangle?

Comment: @eyllanesc, the block and the frame should be drawn without scaling

Comment: if you realize the block is not scaled because its size is independent, but the frame depends on boundingRect(), and boundingRect() is affected when you perform a scale. Why do not you put a fixed size to the frame so you do not have problems with the scale?

Comment: @eyllanesc, if I will apply scaling to the frame then the width of the frame will be scaled too. Also I need to get accurate mapped output rect to calculate the position of the block. If you zoom in the attached images, you will see that at different scales I get different mapped output rect.

Comment: I see that both blocks are the same size, with or without scale: https://imgur.com/a/J7qXe

Comment: You could show me the output you expect when you use scale.

Comment: @eyllanesc, [without scaling](https://imgur.com/a/Uvi2d) and [with scaling](https://imgur.com/a/HOm8Y). The block should be moved top-left by 6px from the bottom right corner, and the frame should be 4px width and drawn inside the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the null pen for the item, and also to adjust the output rect when drawing the frame. So, finally, my code looks like this:

```cpp
#include "Test.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

MyItem::MyItem(QGraphicsItem *parent)
    : QGraphicsRectItem(parent)
{}

void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QGraphicsRectItem::paint(painter, option, widget);

    drawVolumeIndicator(painter);
}

void MyItem::drawVolumeIndicator(QPainter *painter)
{
    static const auto blockColor = QColor(QStringLiteral("#0097a7"));
    static const auto frameColor = QColor(QStringLiteral("#660097a7"));

    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto blockSize = QSize(12, 40);
    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto blockMargin = 2;
    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto frameWidth = 4;
    static Q_CONSTEXPR auto halfFrameWidth = frameWidth / 2;

    const auto outputRect = painter->transform().mapRect(boundingRect());

    painter->save();
    painter->resetTransform();

    // draw block
    const auto x = outputRect.right() - frameWidth - blockMargin - blockSize.width();
    const auto y = outputRect.bottom() - frameWidth - blockMargin - blockSize.height();
    painter->fillRect(QRect(QPoint(x, y), blockSize), blockColor);

    // draw frame
    painter->setBrush(Qt::transparent);
    painter->setPen(QPen(frameColor, frameWidth, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin));
    painter->drawRect(outputRect.adjusted(halfFrameWidth, halfFrameWidth, -halfFrameWidth, -halfFrameWidth));

    painter->restore();
}

Test::Test(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    resize(200, 400);

    auto item = new MyItem;
    item->setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
    item->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    item->setRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    // set scale for the item
    QTransform transform;
    transform.scale(1, 3);
    item->setTransform(transform);

    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(item);

    auto view = new QGraphicsView;
    view->setScene(scene);

    QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(view);
}
```